# Sort a String array by specific String value

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, collections

I have a project where the main functionality is to read a .txt file into a String array and sort it by specific String value in each line. My .txt file is a list of employees with their name, salary ,and experience. Below is my examplary list:

1. Name: Thomas Green | Gross salary: 10 000 | Experience: 30 months
2. Name: Anna Lang | Gross salary: 6 000 | Experience: 12 months
3. Name: Micheal Holse | Gross salary: 8 000 | Experience: 27 months

Now what I want is to sort this list through first name, salary value or experience value, after using a Scanner to change this list into an array. I have read about Comparator, but couldn't find a right example. As you see, what this program has to do is to skip "Name:" value and sort it alphabetically by  first name. Or skip other Strings and sort a list by the lowest salary value. The same for experience it should sort by a number of months from the lowest to the highest.

Here is what I could do until now:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class SortList { 
    public static int loadInt() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        if(!s.hasNextInt()) {
            s.next();
            s.nextLine();   
            return loadInt();
        }
        return s.nextInt();
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{
        //show the list
        String token1 = "";
        Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner (new File ("list.txt")).useDelimiter(",\\s*");

        List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(inFile1.hasNext()) {
            token1 = inFile1.next();
            temps.add(token1);
        }
        inFile1.close();

        String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);         
        for(String s : tempsArray) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        //Sort the list

        System.out.println("How do you want to sort?" + "\n" + "1. By name" + "\n" + "2. By salary" + "\n" + "3. By experience");
        int b;
        b = loadInt();
        if (b == 1){
            ArrayList<String> namesList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0; i<tempsArray.length; i++){
                namesList.add(tempsArray[i]);
            }

            Collections.sort(namesList, (name1, name5) -> name1.split(" ")[1].compareTo(name5.split(" ")[1]));

            for(String name : namesList){
                System.out.println(name);
            }

        }
        if (b == 2){
            ArrayList<String> salaryList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0; i<tempsArray.length; i++){
                salaryList.add(tempsArray[i]);
            }

            Collections.sort(salaryList, (salary1, salary2) -> salary1.split(" ")[10].compareTo(salary2.split(" ")[10]));

            for(String salary : salaryList){
                System.out.println(salary);
            }

        }
        if (b == 3){
            ArrayList<String> experienceList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0; i<tempsArray.length; i++){
                experienceList.add(tempsArray[i]);
            }

            Collections.sort(experienceList, (experience1, experience2) -> experience1.split(" ")[14].compareTo(experience2.split(" ")[14]));

            for(String experience : experienceList){
                System.out.println(experience);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

For now my code doesn't sort the list when I enter a integer value. Is the way I'm doing that is correct? I found example of Collection through internet, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: The real thing here is that you need a reasonable "object" model before doing anything about those various sorting things. In that sense, the answer from dimo is an **absolute must** for you to look into.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But if I create object called Employee, how am I going to load the list from txt file? I'm a beginner in Java, as such I cannot imagine how to load the object from txt file.

Comment: Wow, spent some time to write up a answer for you. Hope that helps, as I got the vague feeling that I wont even see much upvotes for that ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct thing to do is define an `Employee` object with `firstName`, `lastName`, `salary`, and `experience` fields. Then you can define multiple `Comparator<Employee>` instances which support your different sorting options. Then you can create a `List<Employee>` and call [`Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) which will sort the elements based on the ordering defined by the `Comparator`.

This class might look something like this:

```
public class Employee {
  private final String firstName;
  private final String lastName;
  private final int salary;
  private final int experience;

  // constructor, getters
}
```

And your `Comparator` might look something like this:

```
public class FirstNameComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {
  @Override
  public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
    return e1.getFirstName().compareTo(e2.getFirstName());
  }
}
```

Or in Java 8 you can use a method reference, and just pass `Comparator.comparing(Employee::getFirstName)` to the `Comparator` parameter of `Collections.sort()`.

Then it's just a matter of reading the file and extracting the fields from each line and constructing a `Employee` from each one. There are many questions on this site discussing parsing data from text files if you're unsure about that part.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Java 8 solution with `Comparator.comparing`. Most people don't know where to even start with implementing Comparator, so a ready-made solution is extremely helpful.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, however should I create a file with a constructor or   have this part implemented in my program. So the best option is to parse data into comparable fields?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your questions. Classes have constructors, not files; you can define your comparators wherever you'd like - separate files, nested classes inside `SortList`, or even as anonymous classes / lambdas. The key point is to separate the parsing step from the sorting step. Parse the text file into a structured object, then sort those objects.

Comment: @ifly6 yep, Java 8 introduced some great improvements for `Comparator`. In Pre-Java-8-land Guava's [`Ordering`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/OrderingExplained) and [`ComparisonChain`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CommonObjectUtilitiesExplained#comparecompareto) classes serve a similar purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your algorithm is that when you are reading from the file, the `Scanner` object is reading everything at once, and the `ArrayList` temps is getting loaded with just 1 element. Change `token1 = inFile1.next();` to `token1 = inFile1.nextLine();`, everything else is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Further enhancing the suggestion from dimo414. As said, you create a class that contains the relevant pieces for an employee.

That class could have a constructor like

```
public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, int salary, int experienceInMonths)
```

and you would then create employees like

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
employees.add( new Employee ("Bilbo", "Beutlin", 5, 10) );
```

But of course, your date is coming from a file, which you say has lines like

```
Name: Thomas Green | Gross salary: 10 000 | Experience: 30 months
```

So, what you do know:

1. You write code that reads that file line by line
2. You create a helper method that takes one such line ... and returns an Employee object for that

Like:

```
public Employee createEmployeeFrom(String line) {
```

And within that method, you simply have to **parse** that string and extract the relevant information. Given your format, you could do:

- use [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))("\|") ... that should slice your line into *three* substrings
- First substring would be "Name: Thomas Green" then. Here you would use String.substring() to acquire everything after ": "; giving you "Thomas Green". Then you could assume that anything after the last space is the last name; and anything before goes as first name
- Then you do similar things for the parts of your input (using methods such as Integer.valueOf() to turn String numbers into int)
- Finally, you make a call `return new Employee(firstNameParsedFromInput, ....

Things is: you have to separate concerns. One concern is *modeling* your data using an Employee class; the other concern is to parse a string to retrieve the elements that make up an Employee. And only when **all** of that works nicely, you **then** start looking into Collections.sort() and writing your own Comparator class.

Comment: Thanks for the input I will consider this approach when writing the Employee class.

Comment: You are very welcome. And kindly remember my answer once you reach 15 rep and upvote privileges :-)